# Why does nobody try to calculate the possibility to implement quantum computer with math and physics principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

**UPDATED**: Classic computer can be easily implemented in many ways just in different computing velocities, But we have not found any easy way to construct quantum computer scalable by using quantum error correction till now, and in fact, it is not built scalably in any way.

So, why does nobody try to prove and calculate the possibility to to build scalable quantum computer? Quantum threshold theorem is proved with assumption of bounded probability which is a constant. Is the bounded probability infered from physics principle or laws? Or it is just built on some other assumption?
I guess maybe we have made some mistake or misunderstood the quantum theory(the docoherence rate is always faster than  rate of quantum error correction at some scale?), that lead to such a difficult issue.

Comment: It is possible to build a quantum computer. In fact it has been done. The challenge is building *scalable* and *fault-tolerant* quantum computers. There is no fundamental physics obstruction to building them, but it's very hard to do in practice.

Comment: @Andrew I do not think so, because these quantum computers have some loophole in proving they are doing quantum computation.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723342/.                                 
In fact, those two problems are entangled together, if one can be implemented, the other is easy to implent,

Comment: I don't think anyone disagrees that a quantum computer implementing Shor's algorithm has been built, after a google search it looks like $21$ has been factored with Shor's algorithm (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-95973-w). Where people might disagree is whether it is possible to use quantum error correction to build a large and useful quantum computer. Practically speaking, the jury is still out on whether this can be done. On a fundamental level, I think most people would say there is no clear physics argument that it's impossible, but maybe there's room for debate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gil Kalai, among others, believes that it is fundamentally physically impossible to build a large-scale quantum computer and has tried to formalize an argument why. This is very much a minority view in the scientific community.

Comment: You should link to a relevant paper by Kalai such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02499

Comment: See also Dyakonov, who wrote the most reasonable popular treatment that I know of:
https://cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/cosc425/The-Case-Against-Quantum-Computing.pdf

Comment: @alanf I have not read or know any paper about this question, so.....

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There I linked to a paper, so click on the link.

Comment: @alanf thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no fundamental reasons which would *forbid* to build a scalable quantum computer. Some prototypes of QPU with hundreds of qubits are [already built](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-03476-5). Of course they are far from "commercially viable" quantum computer, but with each day new quantum computers are built with increasing number of qubits. Albeit, seems not in the exponential [Moore law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) as in classical computers, and that's understandable, because at the time being we are in the search of scalable technology, which would let to change qubits density on the fly,- print them on quantum integrated circuit as many as we need. Research for such massive qubits imprinting is very active, there are some protocols at least theoretically which could do that,- for example [spin-based qubits creation protocol](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.00836) or [vibrating atom pairs protocol](https://scitechdaily.com/mit-physicists-have-discovered-new-qubits-for-quantum-computers-using-vibrating-atoms/) or dozens of others.
As long as such effective protocol will be found and implemented practically for creating millions of qubits,- some of them will be dedicated to error-correction algorithms and this will indicate an era of commercial quantum computer. Of course there is some degree of faith that such high-density packing of qubits is possible, but this is confirmed at least by theoretical research and the fact that it's not forbidden by any current Physics laws.

Comment: It is not true that "Some prototypes of QPU with hundreds of qubits are already built. "

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There Are you denying [IBM's 127 qubits](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-03476-5) invented quantum chip ?

Comment: IBM's 127 qubits invented quantum chip is propaganda, I think it is a joke.

Comment: @XL_At_Here_There And probably you think that [Google quantum computer codename "Sycamore"](https://medium.com/predict/googles-quantum-computer-is-about-158-million-times-faster-than-the-world-s-fastest-supercomputer-36df56747f7f) is propaganda too ? And [quantum circuit frameworks](https://quantumai.google/cirq) is also a lie and propaganda ? And couple of dozens [physical realization methodologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Candidates_for_physical_realizations) of QPU is also propaganda,- I think you would say ? Not too much nihilism in your view ?

Comment: right， it is what I think about Sycamore.

Comment: For god sake, maybe you'll notice [IonQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IonQ),- trapped Ion based Quantum Computer created by IonQ company ? These companies spawns in quantum computing sector, just because it is possible to do it (at least in terms of hundreds of qubits). Future will show about feasibility of constructing QPU with a lot bigger qubit numbers.